# Why does the bottom in contact with surface sweat more?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

It is summer, I have noticed that when I am sitting, my bottom which is contact with the chair sweats the most.

Why does that happen?

I think it might be because of friction, but I don't  move alot while sitting so I think friction doesnt come to play here.

Thank you.

Comment: I always assumed it was because the sweat can't evaporate.

Answer (score 1):

Because the sweat can’t evaporate into the atmosphere, and it’s the heat required to turn the sweat into a vapour that cools the body down.

Evaporative cooling can be very effective and cheap, check out the Zeer pot.